# Conditional statements doesn't work on Wordpress title tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use as few plugins on my WP site as possible. Therefore I created custom fields for posts and pages to create a title tag and meta description.

The code look as follows:

```
<title>
<?php $title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Title', true);
if ($title) { ?>
<?php echo $title; ?> | domain.com
<?php }
else { ?>
<?php wp_title(''); ?> | domain.com
<?php } ?>
</title>
```

The code works like a charm, unless for one cause. The homepage titletag is similar to the most recent blog posted (my homepage is a blog overview). Obviously I don't want that.

I found that inserting the following code right under `<title>` works

```
<?php if(is_home()) { echo "My desired homepage title tag"; } ?>
```

However, the title tag now contains both the desired title tag AND the title from the custom field. I first thought I could simply solve that by using the logical `if`, `elseif`, `else` contruction and change the following:

```
if ($title) { ?>
```

into `elseif`.

However then my whole site breaks and I get a blank page in return for every URL I try to access.

Then my PHP knowledge stops. I have no idea how to solve the double title. Can someone help me out and point what I'm doing wrong? Why doesn't the conditional statements work

Answer (score 0):

The main reason should be that when you access $post->ID you get the ID of the latest inserted post, not the homepage.
By default wordpress loads the latest post an you have them ready to use in the loop.

To avoid that you have to set a different homepage than "latest posts" in "settings" -> "reading".
Once you do that you'll se the correct title loading up.

Anyway I would advise to use the super useful WordPress SEO plugin by yoast, is the de facto standard for this kind of things and is used by a lot of high traffic wordpress installation.

let me know